# Tilted pole harmonic motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

This is a question i thought on myself while swinging from a hammock.

A pole with mass $m$ and length $k$ is suspended in air by two mass-less strings one at each end of the pole.
One string has length $l$, the other hass length $l/2$.
The system is then pushed until both ropes have an angle $\theta$ with the top.
What is the equation of motion equation for the system? What is the angular frequency $\omega$ of the oscillation?

I tried to find the equation of motion using torque. But I have trouble finding the torque of the tension force of each string using only $\theta$.
I thought also that, if you consider the torque  from a point directly half way between the strings, you get a trapezoid mid segment. And because the pole isn't rotating along its center of mass the torque from the strings should be zero and so $\omega$ should be $\sqrt\frac{g}{\text{midsegment}}  $.

I'd be happy if the solution could use Newtonian physics, since this is the only material I've covered so far.

[image: system]

Comment: The angular acceleration of a simple pendulum depends on its length.  In this case, each segment of your pole will have a different acceleration.  The resulting motion will be very complex and probably not periodic.

Comment: But isn't this system id forced to have only one $\omega$ due to it being a rigid body??I'd be happy to delve into any solution to this even  not from my course material

Comment: It's a simple system.  Build it an see what it does.

Comment: i built it it looks periodic yet i wanna calculate omega